# Rails How to have Link to + Icon both on the same line & clickable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, link-to

I want to make it so that I have the logout icon and the link to logout on the same line and as the same clickable link.

If I do it this way:

```
<li>
  <span><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></span>
</li>
```

I get the icon on a separate line and the icon is not clickable to get to the link.

This is how I did it for the login, since I have a get /login page:

```
<li>
  <a href="/login">
   <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
   <span>Edit Account</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

I am using devise to the login and logout. How could I get it so that the icon and the text and both clickable and on the same line for the signout link since the signout link is a delete and not get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), you can pass block

```
<li>
  <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do %>
    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
      Sign Out
    </span>
  <% end %>
</li>
```